# Обьединение типов данных для вывода в шаблон Golang

Tags: http, golang

> есть файл controllers/catalog.go с содержимым Хендлера

```
func Catalog(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    categories, err := models.GetCategories()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    fmt.Print(categories)
    config.TPL.ExecuteTemplate(w, "catalog.html", categories)
}
```

> И обработчик models/getcategories.go

```
type Cat_tree struct {
    Cat_id    int
    Parent_id int
    Cat_name  string
}

func GetCategories() ([]Cat_tree, error) {
    rows, err := config.DB.Query("SELECT cat_id, parent_id, cat_name FROM categories WHERE active = true ORDER BY Parent_id ASC")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    categories := make([]Cat_tree, 0)

    for rows.Next() {
        cat := Cat_tree{}
        err := rows.Scan(&cat.Cat_id, &cat.Parent_id, &cat.Cat_name)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        categories = append(categories, cat)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return categories, nil
}
```

в итоге хочу в шаблон передать дополнительные параметры типа Титлы к примеру

каким образом к переменной **categories**  добавить еще данных 
Сейчас в шаблоне выводится так

```
   {{range .}}
    <p><a href="/show?getinfo={{ .Cat_id}}">{{ .Cat_id}}</a> - {{ .Parent_id}} - {{ .Cat_name}} <a href="/show?getinfo={{ .Cat_id}}">Показать</a>
    {{end}}
```

Хотел ты добавить переменную {{Title}} ну и т,д

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Добавить нужные поля к структуре `Cat_tree`, заполнять данными итп

или

2) Создать структуру с нужными полями, встроить в нее структуру `Cat_tree` и уже эту структуру передать на выполнение функции `ExecuteTemplate`.
В обоих вариантов не забудь подправить сам шаблон.

Comment: ага, спасибо! Сам уже разобрался ....